# How does subscribing to a calendar work?

Tags: calendar

I was surprised to see a website offering "subscribe to a calendar", by protocol `webcal://` and extension `.ics`. I've never encountered this concept before.

How do these "subscription calendars" work? Like the "National Holidays" feature in calendars?

1. Are they shown with a separate colour in the calendar?
2. Can they be shown/hidden with a toggle?
3. Will I be notified about changes to the calendar?
4. If I unsubscribe, will all events (previous and future) be delete automatically?

(I don't if different applications handle this differently, but I use macOS with the built-in Calendar.)

Comment: This depends almost entirely on the application that handles the calendar file you are downloading. Are you using a built-in application? Are you using some third party program? Just saying "I use macOS" doesn't actually clarify much.

Answer (score 0):

Importing an ICS is normally a one-time event and cannot be revoked
(but I have no experience with calendar on the Mac).

You could examine the `.ics` file, which is a text file, before importing it,
if you wish to assure yourself of its contents.
Each event starts with `BEGIN:VEVENT` and ends with `END:VEVENT`.

For more information on the file format see Wikipedia
[iCalendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar).